# How to check return value of sqlite3

Tags: bash, sqlite

I am working on sqlite3 from a bash script on Linux and trying to figure things out. when  I open a database like this: sqlite3> .open contacts.db 
How I know what is the return value, it does not return anything even if the database does not exist..

Also, what is the return value of the query like: 
SELECT count(_id) FROM contacts;

I want to be able to know if the query was successful from my bash script...

Your help is apreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to get the return value of the sqlite3 command on the script like this?

```
sqlite3 <file> <command>
return_value=$?

echo $return_value
```